# Insert into tables by a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm on SQL Server 2000.

I have a view  `Statistics` containing an UNION ALL with 5 different tables (but with the exactly same structure) in different databases:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         statistics_01.dbo.Stat
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         statistics_02.dbo.Stat
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         statistics_03.dbo.Stat
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         statistics_04.dbo.Stat
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         statistics_05.dbo.Stat
```

This view is used to facilitate updates in the different tables.

The primary key of the tables is the following:

```
[Date] [char](8) NOT NULL,
[Store] [int] NOT NULL,
[EAN] [char](14) NOT NULL,
```

Each table has a different constraint based on the Date:

```
- statistics_01.dbo.Stat, Constraint ([Date] >= '20100101' and [Date] <= '20101231')
- statistics_02.dbo.Stat, Constraint ([Date] >= '20110101' and [Date] <= '20111231')
- statistics_03.dbo.Stat, Constraint ([Date] >= '20120101' and [Date] <= '20121231')
- statistics_04.dbo.Stat, Constraint ([Date] >= '20130101' and [Date] <= '20131231')
- statistics_05.dbo.Stat, Constraint ([Date] >= '20140101' and [Date] <= '20141231')
```

So when an insert is done by the view, depending on the date the insertion is done in the right table.

But the problem is that since i created the DB `statistics_05` and table `Stat` and added that new table in the view, i always get the following message.

> Msg 4416, Sev 16:
>   UNION ALL view `Statistics` is not updatable because the definition contains a disallowed construct. [SQLSTATE 42000]

P.S: I already tried to replace the `*` with all the columns without success...

Thank you for your help

Comment: There must be a conflict between the tables constraints. For example: a check constraint is overlapping between base tables. That is the only thing that could cause this type of action. Could you send a script of your base tables with views definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was due to a different `ANSI_PADDING` for the newly created table statistics_05.dbo.Stat.
The others table of the view had a `ANSI_PADDING` SET on ON, and the last table was created with a `ANSI_PADDING` set on OFF.